# Papers on classical optimization in QAOA

Tags: resource-request, classical-computing, qaoa

Are there any papers on the classical optimization part of QAOA?
What is the most efficient method now?

And how is the classical optimization classified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These papers might help:

1. [Classical Optimizers for Noisy Intermediate-Scale Quantum Devices](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.03004)
2. [Collective optimization for variational quantum eigensolvers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.14030)

Also look at these [optimizers from Pennylane](https://pennylane.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction/optimizers.html).